# Cannot determine type syntax inferred by sorted

Tags: swift

```
var topLevelVariable: XXXX // What type here?

var unsortedVotes: [String:Int] = somedict
let sortedVotes =  unsortedVotes.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

I need to do:

```
topLevelVariable = sortedVotes
```

Problem is that I can't define type of topLevelVariable so it accepts the assignment.
I think the correct type is Array<(key: String, value: Int)>  but i'm not sure and don't know how to make it proper type syntax.

So what is the correct type I should define for topLevelVariable ?

Comment: You already said it - `Array<(key: String, value: Int)>`, or `[(key: String, value: Int)]`, or `[(String, Int)]`, as the simplification goes. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary.sorted` returns an array tuples as `(Key,Value)`. So the return type of sorting `Dictionary<String:Int>` will be `Array<(String,Int)>` or `[(String,Int)]` as the shorthand.

When unsure about types, just use opt+click in Xcode on the variable name and you'll see its type.

```
var topLevelVariable: [(String,Int)]
```

Comment: For me, option-clicking on `sortedVotes` gives `[Dictionary<String, Int>.Element]`, which isn't particularly helpful to someone who likely doesn't know what associated types are.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, this brought me confusion.